# Browser Cache Private S3 Resources

Tags: laravel, security, nginx, amazon-s3, caching

Stack is:

1. Angular
2. Laravel
3. S3
4. nginx

I'm using S3 to store confidential resources of my users. Bucket access is set to `private` which means I can access files either by creating temporary (signed, dynamic) links or by using `Storage::disk('s3')->get('path/to/resource')` method and returning an actual file as a response.

I'm looking for a way to cache resources in user's browser. I have tried to set cache headers to resource response directly on AWS, but since I'm creating temporary urls, they are dynamic and cache is not working in that case.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**: One thing that makes the whole problem even more complex is that security of resources should be intact. It means that I need a way to cache resources, but in the same time I must prevent users from copy-pasting links and using them outside of the app (sharing with others via direct links).

Temporary links in terms of security are still not an ideal solution, since they can be shared (and accessed multiple times) within the period of time they are valid for (in my case it's 30 seconds).

Comment: you could take the 2nd approach (i.e. a "proxy") and set the corresponding cache headers on that.

Comment: @apokryfos could you be more specific?

If you think I should add cache headers to response with a file I'm returning by second approach... I can't use that approach since I'm loading images with `<img src="path/to/resource">`. I don't know am I missing something out there, but I'm really stuck and can't find a good way to do such thing and to keep security of resources intact.

So, I basically need to find a way to return links which are not dynamic and also accessible only to authorized users (he shouldn't be able to just copy that link and reuse outside of the app). It looks impossible.

Comment: Your second approach was something like `return response(Storage::disk('s3')->get('path/to/resource'), 200, [ headers ]);` which can use the cache control headers and you can also use the session as a means of security if the image is to be retrieved for the first time (or when the cache expires).

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for the idea. I'll give it a try for some specific cases where I can actually use that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Caching will work as-is (based on `Cache-Control`, et al.) as long as the URL stays the same.  So, if your application uses the same signed URL for awhile, you'll be fine.

The problem comes when you want to update an expiration date or something.  This of course has different querystring parameters, and is effectively a different URL.  You need a different caching key, but the browser has no concept of this by default.

If it is acceptable for your security, you can create a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker) which uses just the base URL (without querystring) as the cache key.  Then, future requests for the same object on the bucket will be able to used the cached response, regardless of other URL parameters.

> I must prevent users from copy-pasting links and using them outside of the app (sharing with others via direct links).

This part of your requirement is impossible, and unrelated to caching.  Once that URL is signed, it can be used by others.

Comment: Thank you Brad for pointing me into a new direction! I continued my research on this _caching_ topic by looking at **Service Worker** and I must say this is the closest thing to what I need. I'm well aware of the fact that protecting signed URLs without any tailor made mechanism is impossible, but thanks again for pointing that too :)

[How to Cache Files with Service Worker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-caching-files-with-service-worker) is an amazing article that I found and I'll put it here for the future reference.

Answer (score 0):

***You have just add one parameter in your code.***

```
'ResponseCacheControl' => 'no-store'

Storage::disk('s3')->getAwsTemporaryUrl(Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->getAdapter(), trim($mNameS3), \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(config('app.aws_bucket_temp_url_time')), ['ResponseCacheControl' => 'no-store']);
```